# Fetching all the images from server's mysql database in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

```
PHP Code:getImage.php
```

//To fetch image url from the database containig id and image in BLOB type

```
require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql = "select id from images";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


$result = array();

$url = "localhost/ImageUpload/getImage.php?id=";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,array('url'=>$url.$row['id']));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: What is your question? Please [edit](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your post to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: **If you dont tell us what the problem is we cannot help you** ___On either of your questions___

Comment: everytime i try to post my code the stackoverflow keeps on saying erroe. can i mail u my code and can you please post in from your  account???

Answer (score 0):

```
 PHP Code:getImage.php
//To fetch image url from the database containig id and image in BLOB type

<?php

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql = "select id from images";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $result = array();  

    $url = "localhost/ImageUpload/getImage.php?id=";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

        array_push($result,array('url'=>$url.$row['id']));
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);

?>


//To connect to database
PHP Code:dbConnect.php

<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","images") or die('Unable to Connect');




**ANDROID CODES:**
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sapan_c.practice.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFetchImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fetch Images" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>




    Mainactivity.java:

package com.example.sapan_c.practice;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String imagesJSON;

    private static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "url";

    private JSONArray arrayImages = null;

    private int TRACK = 0;

    private static final String IMAGES_URL =< "http://10.0.2.2/practice/getImage.php">;

    private Button buttonFetchImages;
    private ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonFetchImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFetchImages);
        buttonFetchImages.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonFetchImages) {
            getAllImages();
        }
    }

    private void getAllImages() {
        class GetAllImages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Fetching Data", "Please Wait...", true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                imagesJSON = s;
                extractJSON();
                showImage();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uri = params[0];
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetAllImages gai = new GetAllImages();
        gai.execute(IMAGES_URL);
    }

    private void extractJSON() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(imagesJSON);
            arrayImages = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showImage() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = arrayImages.getJSONObject(TRACK);
            getImage(jsonObject.getString(IMAGE_URL));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getImage(String urlToImage) {
        class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                URL url = null;
                Bitmap image = null;

                String urlToImage = params[0];
                try {
                    url = new URL(urlToImage);
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return image;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Downloading Image...", "Please wait...", true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                loading.dismiss();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        GetImage gi = new GetImage();
        gi.execute(urlToImage);



AndroidMainfest.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sapan_c.practice">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: actually the comment one is the method i'm tring but it's not working. please hepl me guys